# Plot is cutting off axes labels

Tags: plotting, output-formatting

I am trying to create a plot with the axes labelled and for some reason the x axis label is getting cutoff. I've tried resizing the plot and it does not fix it. I am using the following code:

[image: Plot with cutoff labels]

The data stored in allData is here, in case you want to recreate the problem.

`allData={{{1,0.00016`},{2,0.00006`},{4,8.`*^-6},{8,7.`*^-6},{16,7.`*^-6},{32,7.`*^-6},{64,6.`*^-6},{128,7.`*^-6},{256,7.`*^-6},{512,7.`*^-6},{1024,8.`*^-6},{2048,0.00001`},{4096,0.000015`},{8192,0.000019`},{16384,0.00003`},{32768,0.000056`},{65536,0.000433`},{131072,0.00071`},{262144,0.001277`},{524288,0.002439`},{1048576,0.004779`},{2097152,0.009294`},{4194304,0.018461`},{8388608,0.036768`},{16777216,0.073468`}},{{1,0.000163`},{2,0.000094`},{4,6.`*^-6},{8,6.`*^-6},{16,6.`*^-6},{32,6.`*^-6},{64,6.`*^-6},{128,6.`*^-6},{256,6.`*^-6},{512,6.`*^-6},{1024,7.`*^-6},{2048,8.`*^-6},{4096,0.000014`},{8192,0.000017`},{16384,0.00003`},{32768,0.000055`},{65536,0.000448`},{131072,0.000714`},{262144,0.001282`},{524288,0.002422`},{1048576,0.004701`},{2097152,0.009263`},{4194304,0.018312`},{8388608,0.036492`},{16777216,0.073259`}},{{1,0.000105`},{2,8.`*^-6},{4,2.`*^-6},{8,2.`*^-6},{16,2.`*^-6},{32,2.`*^-6},{64,2.`*^-6},{128,2.`*^-6},{256,2.`*^-6},{512,2.`*^-6},{1024,3.`*^-6},{2048,5.`*^-6},{4096,9.`*^-6},{8192,0.000014`},{16384,0.000025`},{32768,0.000048`},{65536,0.000393`},{131072,0.000731`},{262144,0.001266`},{524288,0.002407`},{1048576,0.004663`},{2097152,0.009127`},{4194304,0.018178`},{8388608,0.036096`},{16777216,0.071814`}},{{1,0.000105`},{2,0.000015`},{4,2.`*^-6},{8,2.`*^-6},{16,2.`*^-6},{32,2.`*^-6},{64,2.`*^-6},{128,2.`*^-6},{256,2.`*^-6},{512,2.`*^-6},{1024,2.`*^-6},{2048,5.`*^-6},{4096,0.000012`},{8192,0.000013`},{16384,0.000022`},{32768,0.00004`},{65536,0.00039`},{131072,0.000728`},{262144,0.001266`},{524288,0.002402`},{1048576,0.004629`},{2097152,0.009103`},{4194304,0.018147`},{8388608,0.036348`},{16777216,0.072373`}}}`

Comment: try the option `PlotRangeClipping ->False` and/or the option `ImagePadding`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For lengthy labels, [`FrameLabel`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameLabel.html) generally works better. You may also want to consider "Log" scaling.

```
allData = {{{1, 0.00016}, {2, 0.00006}, {4, 8.^-6}, {8, 7.*^-6}, {16, 
     7.^-6}, {32, 7.*^-6}, {64, 6.^-6}, {128, 7.*^-6}, {256, 7.^-6}, {512, 
     7.*^-6}, {1024, 8.^-6}, {2048, 0.00001}, {4096, 0.000015}, {8192, 
     0.000019}, {16384, 0.00003}, {32768, 0.000056}, {65536, 
     0.000433}, {131072, 0.00071}, {262144, 0.001277}, {524288, 
     0.002439}, {1048576, 0.004779}, {2097152, 0.009294}, {4194304, 
     0.018461}, {8388608, 0.036768}, {16777216, 0.073468}}, {{1, 
     0.000163}, {2, 0.000094}, {4, 6.*^-6}, {8, 6.^-6}, {16, 6.*^-6}, {32, 
     6.^-6}, {64, 6.*^-6}, {128, 6.^-6}, {256, 6.*^-6}, {512, 6.^-6}, {1024, 
     7.*^-6}, {2048, 8.^-6}, {4096, 0.000014}, {8192, 0.000017}, {16384, 
     0.00003}, {32768, 0.000055}, {65536, 0.000448}, {131072, 
     0.000714}, {262144, 0.001282}, {524288, 0.002422}, {1048576, 
     0.004701}, {2097152, 0.009263}, {4194304, 0.018312}, {8388608, 
     0.036492}, {16777216, 0.073259}}, {{1, 0.000105}, {2, 8.*^-6}, {4, 
     2.^-6}, {8, 2.*^-6}, {16, 2.^-6}, {32, 2.*^-6}, {64, 2.^-6}, {128, 
     2.*^-6}, {256, 2.^-6}, {512, 2.*^-6}, {1024, 3.^-6}, {2048, 
     5.*^-6}, {4096, 9.^-6}, {8192, 0.000014}, {16384, 0.000025}, {32768, 
     0.000048}, {65536, 0.000393}, {131072, 0.000731}, {262144, 
     0.001266}, {524288, 0.002407}, {1048576, 0.004663}, {2097152, 
     0.009127}, {4194304, 0.018178}, {8388608, 0.036096}, {16777216, 
     0.071814}}, {{1, 0.000105}, {2, 0.000015}, {4, 2.*^-6}, {8, 2.^-6}, {16, 
     2.*^-6}, {32, 2.^-6}, {64, 2.*^-6}, {128, 2.^-6}, {256, 2.*^-6}, {512, 
     2.^-6}, {1024, 2.*^-6}, {2048, 5.*^-6}, {4096, 0.000012}, {8192, 
     0.000013}, {16384, 0.000022}, {32768, 0.00004}, {65536, 
     0.00039}, {131072, 0.000728}, {262144, 0.001266}, {524288, 
     0.002402}, {1048576, 0.004629}, {2097152, 0.009103}, {4194304, 
     0.018147}, {8388608, 0.036348}, {16777216, 0.072373}}};

ListPlot[allData, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"Message Size (Bytes)", "Time (s)"}),
 PlotLegends -> {"40Block", "41Block", "40NonBlock", "41NonBlock"},
 ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", None},
 ImageSize -> Medium,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[allData, Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"Message Size (Bytes)", "Time (s)"}),
 PlotLegends -> {"40Block", "41Block", "40NonBlock", "41NonBlock"},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
 ImageSize -> Medium,
 PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

[image]